# Boot Raspberry Pi 2 with SD card from Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-2, pi-4, boot, sd-card

I have a working setup inside SD card, which I used on Raspberry Pi 4 successfully and now I want to use it also on Raspberry Pi 2.

Currently I cannot make it run. It shows always initial multicolored picture and does not boot. But before, I saw it could boot 2-3 times. I did not find any dependency, why it could boot. In the same time, this SD card works on Rpi4.

General question: can I migrate SD card from RPi4 to Rpi2? Should I change some configuration stuff before?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I have put SD card to a computer and modified config.txt: I added boot_delay=1 and commented the lines #dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d #max_framebuffers=2. After this, OS have been loaded and I did two reboots successfully. And after the 3d one, it stucked on the same color screen..

Comment: Update_2: I changed boot_delay=2 and it started again one time. After reboot, it is showing color screen and green LED flashes 7 times (seems kernel.img not found acc. to google).

Comment: Upd3: I put SD card to computer and did not make any changes. Then I put SD card again to Raspberry and it was loaded.. I'm confused why it is happening like this..

Comment: I'm running into the same problem too.  Neither trick you did work for me, though.  What computer did you read your SD card with?  I assume a Linux machine?